# Proof explanation: Every Cauchy sequence has a limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

I have a bit of a problem with understanding the parts of the proof as stated in my book:

> Lemma: In a complete ordered field, every Cauchy sequence has a limit.
>
> Proof: Let $\left(a_{n}\right)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $F$. By the
> argument of lemma $9.15$ of chapter 9 (carried out in $F$ ) the
> sequence is bounded. Hence so is every subset of elements in the
> sequence. Define $$ b_{N}=\text { the least upper bound of
>  }\left\{a_{N}, a_{N+1}, a_{N+2}, \ldots\right\} $$ This exists by
> completeness. Clearly $$ b_{0} \geq b_{1} \geq b_{2} \geq \cdots $$
> and the sequence $\left(b_{n}\right)$ is bounded below-say, by any
> lower bound for $\left(a_{n}\right)$. Hence we can define $c=$ the
> greatest lower bound of $\left(b_{n}\right)$.
>
> We claim that $c$ is the limit of the original sequence
> $\left(a_{n}\right)$ To prove this, let $\varepsilon>0$. Suppose that
> there exist only finitely many values of $n$ with $$ c-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon<a_{n}<c+\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon $$ Then we may choose $N$
> such that for all $n>N$, $$ a_{n} \leq c-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \text { or } a_{n} \geq c+\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon $$ **But there exists
> $N_{1}>N$ such that if $m, n>N_{1}$ then
> $\left|a_{m}-a_{n}\right|<\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$. Hence $$ \text {
> for all } n>N_{1}, a_{n} \leq c-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon $$ Or $$ \text
> { for all } n>N_{1}, a_{n} \geq c+\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon $$** The
> latter condition implies that there exists some $m$ with $a_{n}>b_{m}$
> for all $n>N_{1}$, which contradicts the definition of $b_{m}$. But
> the former implies that we may change $b_{N_{1}}$ to
> $b_{N_{1}}-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$, which again contradicts the
> definition of $b_{N_{1}}$. It follows that for any $M$ there exists
> $m>M$ such that $$ c-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon<a_{m}<c+\frac{1}{2}
>  \varepsilon $$ Since $\left(a_{n}\right)$ is Cauchy, there exists
> $M_{1}>M$ such that $\left|a_{n}-a_{m}\right|<\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$
> for $m, n>M_{1} .$ Hence for $n>M_{1}$, $$
> c-\varepsilon<a_{n}<c+\varepsilon $$ But this implies that $\lim a_{n}=c$ as claimed.

Specifically I don't understand why the 2 bolded sentences are needed in the proof.

Don't we already establish in the previous assumption (*Suppose that there exist only finitely...*) that for all $n>N,  a_{n} \leq c-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \text { or } a_{n} \geq c+\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon $ and from that, the paragraph afterwards (*The latter condition...*) follows? Why does the Cauchy criterion need to be invoked?

Comment: +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing is to say:

> There is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that, for each $n\geqslant N$, $\displaystyle a_n\leqslant c-\frac\varepsilon2$ or $\displaystyle a_n\geqslant c+\frac\varepsilon2$.

A **much stronger** statement is

> There is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that (for each $n\geqslant N$, $\displaystyle a_n\leqslant c-\frac\varepsilon2$) or (for each $n\geqslant N$, $\displaystyle a_n\geqslant c+\frac\varepsilon2$).

They are far from meaning the same thing. Here's a similar situation: it is **true** that

> Each natural number is even or odd.

But it is **false** that:

> Every natural number is even or every natural number is odd.

Comment: Oops, completely missed that "little" detail. Thank you!